# How to uninstall Foxit Reader from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: uninstall, foxitreader

Foxit Reader is installed in the folder `/home/igor/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader`.
There is an Uninstaller, but it doesn't work. Foxit cannot be found in `dpkg --list` or Synaptic. Terminal cannot remove it, reporting "no such file in directory."
Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by using

```
./maintenancetool
```

, which is located in your foxitreader directory.

~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader

It removes all the files including the file associations (e.g. for *.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Software installed outside of the system indeed is not known/registered to the software management system APT. If there is no reliable uninstaller of the application, or if it does not work, you have no other choice than to manually remove the installed files in as far as you can identify them.

Your application fortunately is installed under your own home directory. Likely, no files will have been installed system wide. You can remove the installed files by deleting the `/home/igor/opt/foxitsoftware` folder. If you cannot delete these folders as normal user, then you will need to assume administrator privileges. One way is to delete the folder using the terminal with the command `sudo rm /home/igor/opt/foxitsoftware`.

The application might have created some hidden configuration files in your home folder as well, either directly as hidden configfiles in yoru home, or as folders/files under `.config`, `.local/share`, etc. Typically, they will bear the name of the program. So do a seach for `foxit` (also try `Foxit` or other combinations if nothing appears), inspect the files that pop up and delete anything that looks like a configuration folder/file.

Comment: Regarding "manually remove," that was the first thing I tried (learned in Windows OS). Doesn't work. The file "opt" has a "lock" label on it, and seems stuck. I keep on searching.

Comment: If you are not the owner of the files (despite the fact that they were created in your home folder), then you will need to assume administrator rights to delete the files. This is done by preceding the delete command with "sudo". I added the precise command in my answer.

Comment: Agree. I don't enter terminal without "sudo." Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple tips to help uninstall (i.e. delete, remove configurations for) software that does not appear in `dpkg --list`:

`sudo apt-get install mlocate` - if the following isn't already installed.

`sudo updatedb` - updates the mlocate database.
`locate -i <packagename> | less` - search the mlocate database.
*(man locate, man updatedb provide minuscule info - these commands help locating files and folders)*

These should first of all locate directories that hold related files, but also reveal where configuration files may reside (e.g. in $HOME/ under .<packagename>/ .cache/ .cache/share/ .config/ - or anything similar).

Also;
find the installation package you used and try to determine what and where (e.g. folder names) there is in it, this may provide more hints on what to use as parameters to locate. If it is a single executable then using e.g. gzip, 7zip or "archive manager" on it may reveal more detail.

Note also;
The package may have added settings for other software that it depends on, a simple delete on such (e.g.) config files may have adverse effects on those software packages.

Comment: Please confirm your answer. The command sudo updatedb doesn't work in the terminal.

Comment: Updated. I expected `mlocate` to be a standard package, maybe it isn't.

Comment: The terminal unswered: <rm: cannot remove '/home/igor/opt/foxitsoftware': Is a directory>

Comment: `man rm`, `cd .../opt`, `rm -rf dir/` - make SURE to not remove more than what you intend. DO `cd .../` then `rm ...` - it is VERY EASY to get it wrong.

Comment: Correct. But up to now, I haven't removed anything.

Comment: ... leaving this now.